# TypeScript Gives an Error while using Zod "No overload matches this call."

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-hook-form, zod

```
email: z
    .string()
    .min(1)
    .email()
    .refine(
      (val, ctx) => {
        return (
          (ctx.signInMethod === "Use phone" && val.length > 0) ||
          ctx.signInMethod === "Use email"
        );
      },
      {
        message: "Email is required.",
      }
    ),
```

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(check: (arg: string) => arg is any, message?: string | Partial<Omit<ZodCustomIssue, "code">> | ((arg: string) => Partial<Omit<ZodCustomIssue, "code">>) | undefined): ZodEffects<...>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(val: any, ctx: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(arg: string) => arg is any'.
> Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(check: (arg: string) => unknown, message?: string | Partial<Omit<ZodCustomIssue, "code">> | ((arg: string) => Partial<Omit<ZodCustomIssue, "code">>) | undefined): ZodEffects<...>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(val: any, ctx: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(arg: string) => unknown'.
> Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.ts(2769)
> Parameter 'val' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
> (parameter) val: any
> Parameter 'ctx' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
> (parameter) ctx: any

```
type SignInMethod = "Use email" | "Use phone";

const formSchema = z.object({
  signInMethod: z.enum(["Use email", "Use phone"]),
  email: z
    .string()
    .min(1)
    .email()
    .refine(
      (val, ctx) => {
        return (
          (ctx.signInMethod === "Use phone" && val.length > 0) ||
          ctx.signInMethod === "Use email"
        );
      },
      {
        message: "Email is required.",
      }
    ),
  phoneNumber: z.string().refine(
    (val, ctx) => {
      return (
        (ctx.signInMethod === "Use email" && val.length > 0) ||
        ctx.signInMethod === "Use phone"
      );
    },
    {
      message: "Phone Number is required.",
    }
  ),
  countryPhoneCode: z
    .string()
    .min(1)
    .refine(
      (val, ctx) => {
        return (
          (ctx.signInMethod === "Use email" && val.length > 0) ||
          ctx.signInMethod === "Use phone"
        );
      },
      {
        message: "Country Code is required.",
      }
    ),
  password: z
    .string()
    .min(8, {
      message: "Password should be at least 8 characters.",
    })
    .max(20, {
      message: "Password cannot contain more than 20 characters.",
    }),
});
```

I tried using `(val, ctx: { signInMethod: SignInMethod })` still same problem. Also, tried the following code:

```
.refine(
      (val, ctx): val is string => {
        if (ctx.signInMethod === "Use phone") {
          return val.length > 0;
        }
        return true;
      },
      {
        message: "Phone Number is required when using phone sign-in method.",
      }
    ),
```